# Как узнать в каком дискорд сервере написано сообщение? C# .NET discord

Tags: c#, .net, discord

Мне для команды бота, нужно знать на каком сервере была написана команда. Я предполагаю что из переменноq SocketMessage можно узнать на каком сервере было сообщений, но как именно это сделать?

Comment: Смотрите контекст (`Context`), в нем есть и `Guild`, и `Channel`, и даже `User`, все это откносится к тому, кто вызывал и от куда.

Answer (score 0):

```
private async Task HandleCommandAsync(SocketMessage socMsg)
{
    int guildID = ((socMsg as SocketUserMessage).Channel as SocketGuildChannel).Guild.Id;
}
```

Comment: Ктож обрабатывает команды через события? В Discord.net принято создавать [модули](https://discordnet.dev/guides/text_commands/intro.html), которые сама библиотека вызовет в нужный момент, ну а в них есть свойство `Context`, которое содержит все, что нужно для команды. Ваш ответ хоть и решает задачу, но это на уровне не знаю... `Hello World`, где человек делает консольный проект, на тяп-ляп кидает туда код и радуется тому, что это работает. Если делать по серьезному - такой подход неуместен.